# Referencing higher timeframe in Pine Script

Tags: function, pine-script

I am writing a strategy that uses 1m chart for entry, but should use a double top or bottom as exit from a different timeframe.
I have a script identifying the tops and bottoms, but I need to rewrite this to be able to reference higher timeframes to make the top and bottom signals.
I am new to this, I know about the security function to request the data from different timeframe but I need help as to where in the code I have to use it to get it working.

```
pivotLeg = input.int(10, "Pivot Length")
tf = input.timeframe(defval = "D", title = "DTDB Timeframe")

var top = array.new_float(na)
var bottom = array.new_float(na)

var topIndex = array.new_int(na)
var bottomIndex = array.new_int(na)

ph = ta.pivothigh(pivotLeg, pivotLeg)
pl = ta.pivotlow(pivotLeg, pivotLeg)

////////////// Top ///////////////////
if not na(ph)
    array.push(top, ph)
    array.push(topIndex, bar_index-pivotLeg)

if array.size(top) > 3
    array.shift(top)
    array.shift(topIndex)

////////////// Bottom ///////////////////
if not na(pl)
    array.push(bottom, pl)
    array.push(bottomIndex, bar_index-pivotLeg)

if array.size(bottom) > 3
    array.shift(bottom)
    array.shift(bottomIndex)

inRange = array.size(top) >= 3 and array.size(bottom) >= 3
////////////////////////// Top Calculation //////////////////////////////////////////////////////    
topPrice = 0.0
isTop = false

if inRange
    topStart = array.get(topIndex, array.size(topIndex)-1)
    topPrice := array.get(top, array.size(top)-1)

    if topPrice < array.get(top, array.size(top)-2) and array.get(topIndex, array.size(topIndex)-2) > array.get(bottomIndex, array.size(bottomIndex)-3)
        topPrice := array.get(top, array.size(top)-2)
        topStart := array.get(topIndex, array.size(topIndex)-2)
    
    max_index = array.indexof(top, array.max(top))
    if topPrice < array.max(top) and array.get(topIndex, max_index) > array.get(bottomIndex, array.size(bottomIndex)-3)
        topPrice := array.max(top)
        topStart := array.get(topIndex, max_index)
        
    isTop := high >= topPrice and high[1] < topPrice and low < topPrice and array.get(bottom, array.size(top)-1) > array.get(bottom, array.size(top)-2)

    var topEnd = 0
    
    if isTop
        topEnd := bar_index
        topLine = line.new(x1=topStart, y1=topPrice, x2=topEnd, y2=topPrice, color=color.lime, width=2)
        topA = label.new(x=topStart, y=topPrice, text="Top 1", color=color.lime, style=label.style_label_down, textcolor=color.black, size=size.normal)
        topB = label.new(x=topEnd, y=topPrice, text="Top 2", color=color.lime, style=label.style_label_down, textcolor=color.black, size=size.normal)
        alert("Double Top In: "+str.tostring(syminfo.ticker), alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)

////////////////////////// Bottom Calculation //////////////////////////////////////////////////////    
bottomPrice = 0.0
isBottom = false

if inRange
    bottomStart = array.get(bottomIndex, array.size(bottomIndex)-1)
    bottomPrice := array.get(bottom, array.size(bottom)-1)
    
    if bottomPrice > array.get(bottom, array.size(bottom)-2) and array.get(bottomIndex, array.size(bottomIndex)-2) > array.get(topIndex, array.size(topIndex)-3)
        bottomPrice := array.get(bottom, array.size(bottom)-2)
        bottomStart := array.get(bottomIndex, array.size(bottomIndex)-2)
    
    min_index = array.indexof(bottom, array.min(bottom))
    if bottomPrice > array.min(bottom) and array.get(bottomIndex, min_index) > array.get(topIndex, array.size(topIndex)-3)
        bottomPrice := array.min(bottom)
        bottomStart := array.get(bottomIndex, min_index)
        
    isBottom := low <= bottomPrice and low[1] > bottomPrice and high > bottomPrice and array.get(top, array.size(top)-1) < array.get(top, array.size(top)-2)

    var bottomEnd = 0
    
    if isBottom
        bottomEnd := bar_index
        bottomLine = line.new(x1=bottomStart, y1=bottomPrice, x2=bottomEnd, y2=bottomPrice, color=color.red, width=2)
        bottomA = label.new(x=bottomStart, y=bottomPrice, text="Bottom 1", color=color.red, style=label.style_label_up, textcolor=color.black, size=size.normal)
        bottomB = label.new(x=bottomEnd, y=bottomPrice, text="Bottom 2", color=color.red, style=label.style_label_up, textcolor=color.black, size=size.normal)
        alert("Double Bottom In: "+str.tostring(syminfo.ticker), alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
```

I have until now just added the input.timeframe that I will use to choose what timeframe that particular code will reference.

Could anybody please explain where I have to use the security function to get this part of my script to calculate referencing a different timeframe as set by input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You double top and bottom detection uses pivot points with arrays.

You need to get the pivot points from the different timeframe and then use the same approach for the higher timeframe.

Essentially, this is the part you need to call the `security()` on.

```
ph = ta.pivothigh(pivotLeg, pivotLeg)
pl = ta.pivotlow(pivotLeg, pivotLeg)
```